# Flutter: suffixIcon making text not centered

Tags: flutter

I have 3 TextFormFields, the last one is for the Password, which means it needs a suffixIcon to show/hide the password, if there is no content, the labels show in the center of the fields, which is the needed look:

[image]

But as soon as some content is added, the password text gets some padding (the size of the icon is added to the content as padding), like this:

[image]

I tried using a Stack, with the TextFormField and an Icon, but if the Icon is on top, the Password field is unclickable, if the Password field is on top, the icon is unclickable.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this padding thing?

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `prefixIcon` inside your `decoration` for your `TextFormField`.

It would look something like this :

```
TextFormField(
    //all your other widget here
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: prefixIcon??Icon(Icons.visibility),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I tried adding a prefixIcon, but the text was still not centered

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with Stack  children `pressed/tap`. Place tappable widget at bottom level of stack.

Here is the password field you can try:

```dart
class PassWordFied extends StatefulWidget {
  PassWordFied({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PassWordFiedState createState() => _PassWordFiedState();
}

class _PassWordFiedState extends State<PassWordFied> {
  bool _isVisiblePassword = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          // isDense: true, //you can test it 
          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _isVisiblePassword = !_isVisiblePassword;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              _isVisiblePassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
            ),
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.7),
          filled: true,
          labelText: "Password"),
      obscureText: _isVisiblePassword,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by keeping the text alignment at the start (left) of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The `suffixIcon` is taking some space on your `TextField` so that the text input won't go below the suffix icon when the user inputs a long text. To balance out this space reduction on the left side, you have to add additional padding to the left side in the `contentPadding` property of `InputDecoration`.

But in order to do this, you need to know first the default `contentPadding` value, so that you don't mess up the existing space for the other sides (top, right, bottom). You can find it in the documentation of [`contentPadding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/contentPadding.html):

> If isOutline property of border is false and if filled is true then contentPadding is EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 8) when isDense is true and EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12) when isDense is false. If isOutline property of border is false and if filled is false then contentPadding is EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 8) when isDense is true and EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 12) when isDense is false.
>
> If isOutline property of border is true then contentPadding is EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 20, 12, 12) when isDense is true and EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 24, 12, 16) when isDense is false.

So for example, if your `TextField` has `isOutline` set to false, `filled` set to false, and `isDense` is also false, the default value of the padding is `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 12)`. Now set the `contentPadding` with additional left padding with the same size as the `suffixIcon` width:

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  // ...
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(48, 12, 0, 12),
)
```

It will now be centered because the left and right paddings are balanced.

[image: TextField screenshot]